# Total numbers between a and b which contains atleast one zero

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics

How to find count of numbers between a and b (inclusive) which contains 0 as their digit. I am not able to get this with the idea which i have used below in my code, it becomes very complex in case of leading zeroes

for ex if a=1 and b=200  total number should be 29 but i am getting 39.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way of doing it?

constraints:

```
1<=a<=b<=10^17
```

code:

```
long long int F(long long int dig, long long int a, long long int num)
{
    if(dig == 0) {
        if(a>0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    if(mem[dig][a])
        return D[dig][a];
    mem[dig][a] = 1;
    long long int ret = 0;
    for(long long int i = 0;i<=9;i++) {
        if(i==num)
            ret=(ret+F(dig-1,a+1,num));
        else
            ret=(ret+F(dig-1,a,num));
    }
    D[dig][a] = ret;
    return ret;
}

long long int solve(long long int x,long long int num)
{
    char cad[100];
    long long int ret = 0;
    long long int a=0,b=0,c=0,j;

    sprintf(cad,"%lld",x);
    int len = strlen(cad);
    long long int qued = len;
    for(long long int i = 0;i < len;i++) {
        qued--;
        long long int d = cad[i] - '0';
        for(j=0;j <d;j++) {
            if(j==num) {
                if(num==0 && i==0)
                    a=a+0;
                else
                    a=a+1;
                ret=(ret+F(qued,a,num));
            }
            else
                ret=(ret+F(qued,a,num));
        }
        if(d==num)
            a=a+1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

solution is -> solve(b+1,0)-solve(a,0)

but i am getting wrong answer with this

the link from which i got the above idea is http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/8221

Comment: You should take a small range of numbers e.g. `a = 1 and b = 20` and see how many of those numbers contain a 0. Then increase the size of the number range, you should see a pattern emerging.

Comment: Think about it combinatorially. There are 10 digits including 0 and nine digits excluding it. Number of numbers in rage containing at least one 0 = total number of numbers in range - number of numbers in range not containing any 0s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you clarify the "leading zeroes" bit? For example, if you have the integers from the interval [5;12], would you then write the numbers as 05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12 or would you write them 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12?

Answer (score 0):

A Simple way to do it would be:

```
    inList = [1, 2, ... n]
    outList = []
    for i in inList:
            for j in len(i):
                    if i%10 || i==0:
                        //there is a 0
                        outList.add(i)
                        break;
                    if(i<10)
                        //i cannot contain a 0
                        break;
                    i=i/10
```

Probibly only works with positive ints, but its trivial to account for negitive numbers.

Simple and efficient O(10N) or O(17N) according to your constraints

Comment: How can it is an efficient way? it takes very large time bcoz N can be as large as 10^17.